# Redirect "Cant't locate xxx.pm in @INC" message to file

Tags: perl, stderr

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Foo.pm # no such file
```

Then run by cron, script falls with message "Can't locate Foo.pm in @INC". It is true.
But I can't see this message (server and cron record out of my control) and unable to detect what file is missing .

Is there any way to redirect this error message to log file?
STDERR redirection doesn't work because error is going at compile time

Comment: "STDERR redirection doesn't work because error is going at compile time." Just redirect STDERR in a `BEGIN` block before you `use Foo.pm`.

Answer (score 1):

I just tested and the following solution does work:

```
./test.pl &> log
cat log

Can't locate Foo.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1 
/usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.10
/usr/share/perl/5.10 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at ./test.pl line 2.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./test.pl line 2.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
# perl -e 'use foo;' >  /var/log/messages 2>&1
# tail /var/log/messages
Can't locate foo.pm in @INC (@INC contains: /etc/perl /usr/local/lib/perl/5.10.1 /usr/local/share/perl/5.10.1 /usr/lib/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 /usr/lib/perl/5.10 /usr/share/perl/5.10 /usr/local/lib/site_perl .) at -e line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at -e line 1.
#
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can modify the cron entry, redirect standard error to standard output or to a file with the notation `2>&1` or `2>/some/file`.

If that is not possible, you can redefine `STDERR` at the start of your script before your modules are loaded. Use a `BEGIN` block **before** any `use` statements that might fail:

```
#! perl
BEGIN {
    open STDERR, '>', '/my/log/file';
}
use ModuleNotFound;
```